# Using the same JavaSparkContext for multiple jobs to prevent using time on spark driver initialization

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, google-cloud-dataproc

I am trying to run Spark jobs on Google Dataproc. However, as its seen typically, the initialization of the Spark Driver takes up a good chunk of the execution time. I would like to know what is a good way to run multiple jobs of Spark on Google Dataproc using the same instance of JavaSparkContext so I don't lose performace every job due to spark driver initialization. Currently, my code looks something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    SparkConf configuration = new SparkConf().setAppName("App");
    final JavaSparkContext context = new JavaSparkContext(configuration);

    // Do stuff

    // Stop connection to Java Spark
    context.stop();
}
```

Comment: I'd like to hear more about your use case; can you mail me (my SO user name, without spaces) at google.com?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dataproc is currently based on YARN for resource allocation as this allows us to have a single interface for Hadoop-based jobs (Hive, Pig, Hadoop MR) and Spark jobs. The downside to this is that there's the overhead of allocating a Spark AppMaster and workers when you start a new (Java)SparkContext. I don't think Dataproc has a built-in answer for you and I think that any solutions that are easily accomplishable will mean that you will no longer use the Dataproc Jobs API to submit individual jobs.

While Dataproc itself cannot currently provide low-latency Spark jobs via the jobs API, you can run a Dataproc cluster and point a Spark Job Server at the Dataproc cluster. You can find more about the job server on github here https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver. When using the job server, you should be able to create a Spark context and then reuse the context for later jobs. You will further want to ensure that you configure the job server to run in yarn-client mode. This means that each context that you create will still incur the startup cost of YARN allocation, but you will only incur that once per context.

If your REST server is running in an environment that cannot make arbitrary network calls (e.g., AppEngine), you may want to investigate a system that publishes a message to cloud pubsub and then have a component running in GCE that subscribes for messages and then submits jobs to the Spark Job Server on behalf of your AppEngine app.